# show two div using select option tag element with submit button

Tags: jquery, html

Yesterday I have raised the same type of question in a different format.  But today i want the same question in a different format.

Here it goes:

I have multiple divs in a page.

When i select one value from the drop down and I click the submit button, I need to show the two divs.

Here is my html code :

```
 <div id="one">
                  <h1>
                    Security
                      <div class="hdrhr" style="width:5%">&nbsp;</div>
                  </h1>
             </div>
             <div id="two"  class="hidden">
                  <h1>
                    Customer Type
                      <div class="hdrhr" style="width:5%">&nbsp;</div>
                  </h1>
             </div>


<form onSubmit="javascript: return false;">
                                    <select name='dropDown' id='dropDown' style="width:205px;padding:4px;margin-left:-2px;">
                                        <option value="one">Security</option>
                                        <option value="two">Customer Type</option>
</select>
```

Here is the button 
    Get Details

```
 <div id="one" class="roundedCorner">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                            <td align="center" class="parentalhdtlnt" style="color:#ffffff;width:5%">
                               Id_User
                               <br />
                               <input type="text" name="Member" class="ipttxt" tabindex="1" />
                            </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
 <div id="two" class="roundedCorner">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                            <td align="center" class="parentalhdtlnt" style="color:#ffffff;width:5%">
                               Id_User
                               <br />
                               <input type="text" name="Member" class="ipttxt" tabindex="1" />
                            </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is my js code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#goBttn").click(function(){
            $("#"+$("#dropDown").val()).show();
            select = document.getElementById("dropDown").getElementsByTagName("option");
            select = document.getElementById("hdrlbl").getElementsByTagName("option");
            for(x=0;x<=select.length;x++)
                if($(select[x]).val()!=$("#dropDown").val()) $("#"+$(select[x]).val()).hide();
                if($(select[x]).val()!=$("#hdrlbl").val()) $("#"+$(select[x]).val()).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

In a drop down if i selecting security i need to show the heading div and as well as content div the same for customer type

Kindly bear me the formatting of the code.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance
SKM

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery with core JS?

Comment: Where's your button in the HTML?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve. Please explain in detail.

Comment: hi @Michael_B i am extremely sorry i will edit this question just give me minute

Comment: When you say you need to show 2 divs, which divs are you referring to?

Comment: hi @Mihir actually i am new jquery and javascript i was not so sure this is the right way kindly bare with me

Comment: No problem, but we need some more details.

Comment: Appears that you want to choose one of the Div based on selection of the drop down item. Is that true?

Comment: hi @Mihir see what excatly i want is if i select securiy option from the drop down and if i click the button i.e anchor tag i need to show div.... one is header div and second is content div... same for customer type..... this is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time restructuring the code as a whole since it looks a bit unorganized to me. Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccw24/

HTML

```
<div class="headerCont switchArea">
    <div data-ref="one">Header One (Security)</div>
    <div data-ref="two">Header Two (Customer Type)</div>
</div>

<select name='dropDown' id='dropDown'>
    <option value="one">Security</option>
    <option value="two">Customer Type</option>
</select>
<a href='#' id="pageChange">Go</a>

<div class="footerCont switchArea">
    <div data-ref="one">Footer One (Security)</div>
    <div data-ref="two">Footer Two (Customer Type)</div>    
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pageChange").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var ref = $('#dropDown').val();
        $('.switchArea > div').hide();
        $('div[data-ref="'+ref+'"]').show();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.switchArea > div {
    display: none
}

.switchArea > div:first-of-type {
    display: block
}
```

Just a note: This code uses some more modern techniques that may not work well with older browsers (Old IE, I am looking at you) so if you need compatibility with those browsers then you may need to do some tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/dqVy2/10/

HTML:

```
<div id="one" class="one hidden">
     <h1>Security
                      <div class="hdrhr" style="width:5%">&nbsp;</div>
                  </h1>

</div>
<div id="two" class="two hidden">
     <h1> Customer Type
                      <div class="hdrhr" style="width:5%">&nbsp;</div>
                  </h1>

</div>
<form onSubmit="javascript: return false;">
    <select name='dropDown' id='dropDown' style="width:205px;padding:4px;margin-left:-2px;">
        <option value="one">Security</option>
        <option value="two">Customer Type</option>
    </select>
    <button id="goBttn">GO</button>
</form>
<div id="one" class="one roundedCorner hidden">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="parentalhdtlnt" style="color:#ffffff;width:5%">Id_User
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="Member" class="ipttxt" tabindex="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="two" class="two roundedCorner hidden">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="parentalhdtlnt" style="color:#ffffff;width:5%">Id_User
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="Member" class="ipttxt" tabindex="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#goBttn").click(function () {
        $("#dropDown").find("option").each(function () {
            var div_id = $(this).val();
            $("." + div_id).each(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
        $("." + $("#dropDown").val()).each(function () {
            $(this).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I assume you meant you need to show them separately...I cycle through each option and hide any divs with IDs matching that val of a the option...then show the selected option's div.

Comment: hi @michael thanks for the reply but one small change sorry for the change here if i select one value from dropdown i need to show two div that is header div and content div again for the next one also kindly bare me here

Comment: Is the `content` div the one that has the same id, but with `roundedCorner` as it's class?

Comment: It's not a best practice to have two elements with the same ID.  But I believe I understand what you are doing/wanting.

Comment: thank u so much for your prompt reply see what exactly i want is 

i have select option drop down if i select one value and if i click go button i need to show header div and content div both the id's will different 

kindly help me here